# Implementing an automation task

Tags: automation

I am looking to implement some automation on my computer.

I want to copy a file from a source directory into multiple folders of a target directory, and rename each copy to its original name plus the name of the folder.

What's the best way to go about this? Should I use Visual Basic or another programming language?

Comment: You should specify an operating system. One could assume you mean Windows, since you mentioned VB, but it's good to specify.

Comment: I believe even under Windows, the task is most easily done with a bash script. It can be done with two nested `for` loops.

Comment: Bash would be easy, but it would have to be installed. VBScript or PowerShell would be native to Windows.

Comment: There really is no best way, there is only the way you are most comfortable. VB.net, vbscript, bash, autoit, perl, python, etc. Any of them are perfectly appropriate for the task at hand. If you are familiar with Visual Basic, then by all means, use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses.

I found a good solution for my particular task. It's [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), a free scripting environment. It even has UI capabilities.

Comment: It has a successor in AutoHotKey as well; I couple AHK and Python to accomplish a lot of automagic.